# While persisting many to one relation in Spring with JPA, it adding additional unecessary parent entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

The problem is when I try to persist WordPair and link Dictionary entity to it, hibernate persists new Dictionary entity and then persists new WordPair entity with attaching new dictionary to it. How to attach existing dictionary entity, which I have chosen with form:select item in view? If I change

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.All)
```

option in WordPair to Merge or something, it gives

java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:

My view is the following:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="wordpair" action="addWordPair" method="post">
        <label for="semanticUnitOne">Enter word one: </label>
        <form:input path="semanticUnitOne"/>
        <br/>

      <label for="semanticUnitTwo">Enter word two: </label>
      <form:input path="semanticUnitTwo"/>
      <br/>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dictionary">Dictionary</label>
          <form:select path="dictionary" cssClass="selectpicker" items="${dictionaries}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id">
              <%--<form:options items="${dictionaries}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>--%>
          </form:select>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add word pair"/>

  </form:form>

  <div class="control-group">
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller is the following:

```
@Controller
public class WordPairController {

@Autowired
WordPairService wordPairService;

@Autowired
DictionaryService dictionaryService;

@RequestMapping(value = "createWordPair", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createWordPair(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("wordpair", new WordPair());
    model.addAttribute("dictionaries", this.dictionaryService.findAll());
    return "addWordPair";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "addWordPair", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addWordPair(@ModelAttribute("wordpair") WordPair wordPair, BindingResult result, Dictionary dictionary) {

    wordPair.setDictionary(dictionary);
    wordPairService.save(wordPair);
    return "addWordPair";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "wordPairGet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String wordPairGet(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("wordPair", wordPairService.findAllWordPairs());

    return "wordPairGet";
}

}
```

Entitiy for dictionary is the following:

```
@Entity
public class Dictionary {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String name;
private String comment;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dictionary", cascade = CascadeType.All, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<WordPair> wordPairs;
```

and wordpair entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class WordPair {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String semanticUnitOne;
private String semanticUnitTwo;
private int rating;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.All)
private Dictionary dictionary;
```

Also there is a service and DAO,

```
@Repository("dictionaryDao")
public class DictionaryDaoImpl implements DictionaryDao {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public Dictionary save(Dictionary dictionary) {
    em.persist(dictionary);
    em.flush();

    return dictionary;
}


public List<Dictionary> findAllDictionaries() {
    List<Dictionary> result = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Dictionary d", Dictionary.class).getResultList();
    return result;
}


@Repository("wordPairRepository")
public class WordPairDaoImpl implements WordPairDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


public List<WordPair> findAllWordPairs() {
    List<WordPair> result = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM WordPair p", WordPair.class).getResultList();
    return result;
}

public WordPair save(WordPair wordPair) {
    em.persist(wordPair);
    em.flush();
    return wordPair;
}
```

Comment: When you persist your WordPair , does the Dictionary in it has Primary Key Id ! . For update operations you must use the em.merge() .

Comment: It has totally Dictionary entity inside. It is not the update operation, I want to persist wordpair. And I don't know if it is enough to put dictionary enty in controller as follows: wordPair.setDictionary(dictionary);    wordPairService.save(wordPair); But debuging shows that it has it.

Answer (score 2):

use @joinColumn as Wordpair table id as below wordpairId in WordPair class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class WordPair {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String semanticUnitOne;
private String semanticUnitTwo;
private int rating;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =javax.persistence.CascadeType.All)
@JoinColumn(name = "WordPairId")
private Dictionary dictionary;
```

see below Dictionary Class targetEntity as WordPair.class

```
@Entity
public class Dictionary {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String name;
private String comment;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dictionary", cascade = CascadeType.All,fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = WordPair.class)
private List<WordPair> wordPairs;
```

Comment: it works, but it doesn't persist Dictionary_id into database

Comment: I think problem is somewhere in view (with select option) or controller. Dictionary is not binding in view and controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in controller and not in JPA. It was necessary to get Dictionary on the basis of chosen ("select") option. And only than add it to the wordpair:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "addWordPair", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addWordPair(@ModelAttribute("wordpair") WordPair wordPair, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("dictionary") Long dictId) {

        Dictionary specificDictionary = dictionaryService.getById(dictId);
        wordPair.setDictionary(specificDictionary);
        wordPairService.save(wordPair);

        return "addWordPair";
    }
```